# Adobe Air Capabilities.os returns wrong version of Windows

Tags: windows, actionscript-3, air, windows-10

Simplest code example: in a fresh desktop air project, with a few lines of code:

```
import flash.system.Capabilities;
trace(Capabilities.os); // returns "Windows 8" on a Windows 10 machine
```

I haven't tried it on systems where Windows 10 has been installed from scratch, but on both a windows 7 -> windows 10 upgrade and a windows 8 -> windows 10 upgrade, it looks like Air's Capabilities class is returning the wrong value, even though I can run something like `wmic os get Caption` on the command line and get back "Microsoft Windows 10."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a known bug in the current AIR SDK.  Check out https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=4031494

Comment: ah thanks, I tried poking around a bit to see if I could find any official mention, I probably didn't look hard enough. I ended up doing a super hacky workaround, launching a .cmd from air and reading out and parsing whatever the command line spat out. works for now at least.